# jQuery: delay disable button onclick after the form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So right now I have this:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="usp-submit usp-submit-default"  onclick="return change(this); "  id="btnSubmit" />
```

jQuery:

function change( el )

```
{
    if ( el.value === "Send" )
        el.value = "Sending";
    else
        el.value = "Please wait...";

$("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
    
}
```

This does disable the input button and change the value to "Please wait", but the form is not submitted.

I assume this disables the button in the first place and doesn't perform the send action.

I have read somewhere that you can add a delay before `.attr("disabled", true)` for a few milliseconds so that the form would be submitted first.

Any help from jQuery experts would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delay, you can use the vanilla js way, `setTimeout()`

```
function change( el )
{
    if ( el.value === "Send" )
        el.value = "Sending";
    else
        el.value = "Please wait...";

    setTimeout( () => $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true) , 0);
}
```

Comment: hey Learning Mathematics, `return true;`  doesn't change anything. Same result. The form won't submit. Do you know how to add a slight delay before `$("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);` ?

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed. Thanks a ton!